# отсортировать буквы и цифры javascript

Tags: javascript

дана строка из букв и цифр. надо отсортировать что бы буквы ушли вперед, а цифры назад. Вот так должно выглядить (' we2t3yt4 ') = а в конечном (' wetyt234 ')

Comment: Ну вроде в два цикла элементарно делается (или даже в один чуть менее элементарно), какие проблемы у вас возникли при решении данной задачи?

Comment: а что делать с пробелами внутри строки между цифрами и буквами? и в начале/конце строки

Answer (score 2):

Ну, как вариант ...

```js
const str = 'we2t3yt4';
const letters = str.match(/[a-z]+/g);
const numbers = str.match(/\d+/g);

console.log(letters.concat(numbers).join(''));
```